# How to add/save Postal Address to Contacts in Android Application

Tags: android, contactscontract, android-contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add postal address to contacts in android programmaticaly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045779/how-to-add-postal-address-to-contacts-in-android-programmaticaly)

I am trying to save postal address to contacts in my android application, but all I am able to save is email and phone number. Postal address is never saved to that contact.
Please help me how to proceed with this.